# How to get access to the derived std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Suppose I have code like that one, and I want to get access to the myClassB members. How can I do that? I need to use the functionality of functionA.
I can't change it because it is from the 3rd party library. And I need to use functionA to create it, and get values created by it. In this case "Test_1" string

```
class myClassA {
public:
    myClassA(){}
    ~myClassA(){}
};

class myClassB : public myClassA
{
public:
  myClassB(){}
  void setString1(std::string newString)
  std::string getS1()     
private:
  std::string privateMember;
};

std::shared_ptr<myClassA> functionA()
{
  std::shared_ptr<myClassB> temporary(new myClassB());
  temporary->setString1("TEST_1");
  return std::move(temporary);
}

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<myClassA> myPtr; // = functionA(); ??
}
```

Comment: move is not needed in return statement. clang will even complain about this.

Comment: What about the member of class A, can you change it?

Comment: no I can't I have access just to the functionA

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, you could use a `dynamic_cast` (or in this case specifically, `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to get the derived pointer type. Like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClassA> a_ptr = functionA();
std::shared_ptr<MyClassB> b_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<MyClassB>(a_ptr);
if(b_ptr) {//Check to verify the cast was successful
    b_ptr->setString("Test1");
}
```

There is, however, a major caveat to this. In order for `dynamic_cast` (and therefore `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`) to work, your object hierarchy must have a virtual table defined. That means at least one of the methods defined by `MyClassA` must be declared `virtual`. The simplest solution is to declare the destructor `virtual`, since that's good practice whenever you're defining polymorphic objects (since you need it to ensure that any derived classes clean up their resources correctly).

```
class MyClassA {
public:
    MyClassA() = default;
    virtual ~MyClassA() = default;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to use functionA to create pointer

Comment: @pZCZ That's fine. `std::make_shared` is just syntactic sugar for what `functionA` does in its first line of code.

Comment: still, dont know how to get values set by functionA in this case I need to get "TEST_1" string. Sorry for being not to specific.

Comment: @pZCZ Inside the `if` statement, after you've verified the validity of `b_ptr`, `b_ptr` is a 100% authentic pointer to an object of type `MyClassB`. It can be used the same as any other pointer to `MyClassB`. So you can call `b_ptr->getS1();`, and it'll do exactly what you expect it to do.

Comment: Far more succinct and tidy in terms of scoping would be to write `if ( auto const b_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<MyClassB>(a_ptr) ) { /* Use b_ptr */ }`

Comment: @Xirema b_ptr is a 100% authentic pointer to an object of type MyClassB but I need to have access to the object exactly returned by functionA

Comment: @pZCZ And you will. You may need to spend some time with a C++ fundamentals book, since a proper resource would have taught you this before you started working with pointers. [Some suggested reading is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My previous comments were for your code before you edit the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with `dynamic_cast` but without a virtual function table in ClassA, something like this would have to do:

[Test This Code](http://cpp.sh/2gpx)

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class myClassA {
public:
    myClassA(){}
    ~myClassA(){}
};

class myClassB;
class ClassB_Registry{
    private:
    ClassB_Registry(){
    }
    ~ClassB_Registry(){
    }
    public:
    static ClassB_Registry* Get(){ static ClassB_Registry obj; return &obj; }
    static void Register(myClassB* ptr){
        Get()->mPointers.insert(ptr);
    }
    static void UnRegister(myClassB* ptr){
        Get()->mPointers.erase(ptr);
    }
    static myClassB* Cast(myClassA* ptr){
        if(Get()->mPointers.count((myClassB*)ptr) > 0) return (myClassB*)ptr;
        return nullptr;
    }

    private:
    std::set<myClassB*> mPointers;
};



class myClassB : public myClassA
{
public:
myClassB(){ ClassB_Registry::Register(this); }
~myClassB(){ ClassB_Registry::UnRegister(this); }
void setString1(std::string newString){privateMember = newString;}
std::string getS1() { return privateMember; }
private:
std::string privateMember;
};

std::shared_ptr<myClassA> functionA()
{
std::shared_ptr<myClassB> temporary(new myClassB());
temporary->setString1("TEST_1");
return std::move(temporary);
}

int main()
{
std::shared_ptr<myClassA> myPtr = functionA(); //??
std::shared_ptr<myClassA> myPtr_a(new myClassA()); //??
myClassB* pDerrived = ClassB_Registry::Cast(myPtr.get()); // bridge the RTTI gap
if(pDerrived) 
    std::cout << pDerrived->getS1();

pDerrived = ClassB_Registry::Cast(myPtr_a.get()); // works on A pointers to return null
if(pDerrived) 
    std::cout << pDerrived->getS1() << "    \n";
else
    std::cout << "Not A Pointer of Type B" << "    \n";
}
```

It's not pretty, but if myClassB had a virtual table as mentioned previously, and all future derived classes used `myClassB` as the base, then you could bridge the gap for RTTI.